# hacking gnome 3 from gnome-shell.css file

Tags: css, linux, redhat, gnome

I wanted to hack gnome, gnome 3 to be specific, on red hat 7. I wanted to get rid of the top panel in its totality. Im new to this, so I looked around and went to the gnome-shell.css file. There I found something called "panel" which looks like the only possible place for what im thinking is that top bar on the desktop. In here i wrote "display : none", nothing happens, the top panel is still there. Do I have to get the source code for gnome and make my modifications from there(i hope not)!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't, you were able to do that on previous version of Gnome (following this path /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel and blank it). The only thing you can do is this : apply this extension to hide top panel which is called "hide top bar". When 
full screen mode is required (probably because you're enlarging an application window) it automatically hides the top panel. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Gnome3 is not as out-of-the-box customizable as Gnome2. Since you can't really get the same functionality with Gnome3 as Gnome2, perhaps try a different GUI, like [XFCE](https://xfce.org/) which lets you easily customizes you panels.